# Lazarus: Reading small text files into memory to process line by line

Tags: text-files, lazarus

I have 400 small text files (less than 30 kb) that I wish to parse. The number of lines per file varies from 100 to about 250. Line length varies from 8 characters to about 1200 characters.

My present program reads through the directory, opens each file in turn and then uses readln to parse each file line by line.

What I would like to do is read each file *** once**  into memory and then have some way to  **access and parse each line *** while the whole file is in memory.

Can someone suggest which Lazarus functions would be best to use to accomplish this?

Thank you.

Comment: Use a TStringList instance for each file - I am not a Lazarus user but I think it has this class.

Answer (score 1):

As @500 - Internal Server Error mentioned, loading each text file into a Stringlist is the easiest way to do this.

```
MyList := TStringList.Create;
MyList.LoadFromFile('file.txt');
```

Answer (score 1):

@nepb just don't forget to free MyList after you have finished with it:

```
MyList := TStringList.Create;
MyList.LoadFromFile('file.txt');
//Do stuff with MyList
MyList.free;
```

Answer (score 0):

or loading them into a TmemoryStream if you are prepared to handle the line breaks yourself.  In a memorystream you can access a byte at a time, ideal for parsing.